# Using Data Annotations with EF6

Tags: wpf, annotations, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I am using WPF with a Database First Entity Framework 6 model. Since it is Database-first, there are no data annotations like `Key` or `Required` in the created model. Since all the created `class` are `partial`, I can easily add data annotations manually. Is there any side effect to that? Is it actually a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any side effect to that?

No, not that I can see. The attribute itself doesn't really change or mean anything unless there is some piece of code that evaluates the attribute(s) at runtime.

In ASP.NET MVC the default model binder does this for you, but in WPF the framework doesn't automatically evaluate data annotations. You could do this yourself in a view model class though. Please refer to the following blog post for more more information about how to do this: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/.

> Is it actually a good practice?

Data annotations are not really part of WPF's built-in data validation functionality. The best practice when it comes to validation is to implement the [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) in your view model classes. But the implementation itself could certainly evaluate the data annotations of an entity/model class using the `ValidationContext` class as described on the link above. I would consider this to be good practice if you are actually using your data annotated entity classes in your WPF application.

Comment: After reading your blog, I have decided to use `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. I just have one question. Should I make the `viewmodel` a `partial class` and break it up into chunks like `DataErrorInfoImplementations`, `Properties`, `Methods` etc?

Comment: You don't have to. It might be an idea do to so if the class is very large for some reasons.